# Attempt to de-reference a null object error after selecting Visualforce page dropdown value

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I'm a beginner developer and I'm building a custom new contract button with a visualforce page with dropdown field values that unhide other fields depending on what is selected.

Clicking the button takes me to the visualforce page with no issues, but when I try to select a dropdown value (in this example "Yes" for Contract Questionnaire) it brings me to the error below...

Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!setContractorQuestionnaire}' in page societycontractrequestform: Class.SocietyContractRequest.setContractorQuestionnaire: line 24, column 1

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contract" extensions="SocietyContractRequest" recordSetVar="sobjects">
    <Script>
        function setFocusOnLoad() {}
    </Script>    
      <apex:form >        
        <apex:pageMessages />                         
        <apex:pageBlock id="contractBlock" title="Contract Request Form" >            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContractInfo" showHeader="true" title="Contract Information" collapsible="false">
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Date_of_Request__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Requester_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Project_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Project_Number__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContractorInfo" showHeader="true" title="Contractor Information" collapsible="false">    
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Legal_First_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Legal_Last_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Operating_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Street__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_City__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_State_Province__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Zip_Postal_Code__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Email_Address__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Contractor_Phone_Number__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Signing_Authority__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Sub_Contracting__c}" />              
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContractorQuestionnaire" showHeader="true" title="Contractor Questionnaire" collapsible="false">
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Questionnaire_Complete__c}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setContractorQuestionnaire}" reRender="ContractorQuestionnaire"  />
                </apex:inputField>  
            </apex:actionRegion>    
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Questionnaire_Completion_Date__c}" rendered="{!ContractorQuestionnaire}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContractorIncorpInfo" showHeader="true" title="Contractor Incorporation Information" collapsible="false">        
                <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Are_You_Incorporated__c}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setContractorIncorpInfo}" reRender="ContractorIncorpInfo"  />
                </apex:inputField>  
                </apex:actionRegion>    
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Incorporation_Number__c}" rendered="{!ContractorIncorpInfo}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Incorporation_Province_Territory__c}" rendered="{!ContractorIncorpInfo}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="WorkersCompInfo" showHeader="true" title="Workers Compensation Information" collapsible="false"> 
                <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Workers_Compensation_Status__c}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setWorkersCompInfo}" reRender="WorkersCompInfo"  />
                </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Workers_Compensation_A_C_Number__c}" rendered="{!WorkersCompInfo}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Workers_Compensation_Province_Territory__c}" rendered="{!WorkersCompInfo}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Proof_of_Exemption_Uploaded__c}" rendered="{!WorkersCompInfoEX}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Clearance_Certificate_Uploaded__c}" rendered="{!WorkersCompInfo}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="GSTHSTInfo" showHeader="true" title="GST/HST Information" collapsible="false">       
                <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Do_you_have_a_GST_HST_Number__c}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setGSTHSTInfo}" reRender="GSTHSTInfo"  />
                </apex:inputField>  
                </apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.GST_HST_Number__c}" rendered="{!GSTHSTInfo}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="MonitorDeliverables" showHeader="true" title="Monitoring of Deliverables" collapsible="false">   
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Deliverables_Supervisor_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Deliverables_Supervisor_Title__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="SourceOfFunds" showHeader="true" title="Source of Funds" collapsible="false">    
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Source_Award_Code__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Source_Program_Area__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContractValueInfo" showHeader="true" title="Contract Value Information" collapsible="false"> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Fee_for_Service_Amount__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Fee_for_Service_Additional_Notes__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Expenses_Amount__c}" />
                <apex:outputField value="{!contract.Total_Contract_Value__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="ContextOfWork" showHeader="true" title="Context of Work" collapsible="false">        
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Context_of_Work__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="DescriptionOfWork" showHeader="true" title="Description of Work" collapsible="false">    
                <apex:inputField value="{!contract.Description_of_Work__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
             
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveForm}" value="Save Contract" />        
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelPage}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />                
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extension...

```
public with sharing class SocietyContractRequest{
        
    public Contract Contract {get;set;}    
    
    public Boolean ContractorQuestionnaire{get;set;}
    public Boolean ContractorIncorpInfo{get;set;}
    public Boolean WorkersCompInfo{get;set;}
    public Boolean WorkersCompInfoEX{get;set;}
    public Boolean GSTHSTInfo{get;set;}
    
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    
    public SocietyContractRequest(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    
    public SocietyContractRequest(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        this.ssc = controller;
    }
    
    //If Questionnaire Complete is Yes then render the Contractor Questionnaire detail fields
    public void setContractorQuestionnaire(){
        if (contract.Questionnaire_Complete__c == 'Yes' ){
            ContractorQuestionnaire = true;
        }else{
            ContractorQuestionnaire = false;            
        }
    }
    
    //If Contractor Incorporated is Yes then render the Contractor Incorporation detail fields
    public void setContractorIncorpInfo(){
        if (contract.Are_You_Incorporated__c == 'Yes' ){
            ContractorIncorpInfo = true;
        }else{
            ContractorIncorpInfo = false;            
        }
    }   
    
        //If Workers Compensation Status is Yes then render the Contractor Questionnaire detail fields
    public void setWorkersCompInfo(){
        if (contract.Workers_Compensation_Status__c == 'Owns WC Account' ){
            WorkersCompInfo = true;
            WorkersCompInfoEX = false;
        }else if (contract.Workers_Compensation_Status__c == 'Exempt from WC' ){
            WorkersCompInfo = false;
            WorkersCompInfoEX = true;
        }else {
            WorkersCompInfo = false;
            WorkersCompInfoEX = false;
        }
    }
    
        //If Questionnaire Complete is Yes then render the Contractor Questionnaire detail fields
    public void setGSTHSTInfo(){
        if (contract.Do_you_have_a_GST_HST_Number__c == 'Yes' ){
            GSTHSTInfo = true;
        }else{
            GSTHSTInfo = false;            
        }
    }
    
    
    //Save page
    public PageReference saveForm(){
        system.debug('Saving Contract...');
        upsert contract;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contract.Id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
       }
       
    //Cancel and return to the CRA Activity Report page
    public PageReference cancelPage(){
        PageReference contractPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(contract).view();
        contractPage.setRedirect(true);
        return contractPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is likely that you contract is null. You will need to set it in the constructor. Have a look at this, line 9  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

Comment: That worked! Thanks... I figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you contract is null. You will need to set it in the constructor.

`this.contract = (Contract)stdController.getRecord();`